# How to change Wi-Fi MAC in Bluestack to a Specific One

Tags: bluestacks

I am using Bluestack 0.9.7.4101 which is already rooted. I want to change its Wi-Fi MAC Address as that of my moblie. So is there any way to change Bluestack Wi-Fi MAC to a specific one? For example, `11:22:33:44:55:66`.

I installed BusyBox and Terminal Emulator, but unable to change Wi-Fi MAC, as it has two MAC addresses, so please help to change only the Wi-Fi MAC.